# Import Rxjs in angular2?

Tags: angular

How to import everything(like operators, observables,......,.....) on a single import from Rxjs in angular2(ts)?

How to use everything of RxJs  by using single import in angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
```

And use it like

```
let obs = Rx.Observable.of(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#es6-via-npm) for Rxjs.

Just do:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

You can access individual operators/observables etc using:

```
 Rx.Observable.<operator>
```

However importing all operators is generally unnecessary and I suggest you import only those operators which you use into a separate **ts** file and then import the particular file into your other files.